# StreamReader.BaseStream issue after using EndOfStream property

Tags: c#, stream, filestream, streamreader

First of all I understand that I can solve this issue using different ways. I guess that this issue exists only because of using different methods in incorrect way. But I want to find out what exactly happened in my example.

I was using StreamReader for reading file. In order to get bytes from it I decided to use BaseStream.Read:

```
        int length = (int)reader.BaseStream.Length;
        byte[] file = new byte[length];
        while(!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            int readBytes = reader.BaseStream.Read(file, 0, 
                (length-offset)>bufferSize?bufferSize:(length - offset));
            for (int i = 0; i<readBytes; i++)
            {
                ...
            }
            offset += readBytes;
        }
```

BaseStream.Read refuses to get last 1024 bytes when property StreamReader.EndOfStream was used before reading. Later I've found information, that EndOfStream trying to read 1 byte, but in fact he reads 1024 bytes due performance. Apparently this 1kb become impossible to reach.

**EDIT:** If I delete **reader.EndOfStream** property in code, **reader.BaseStream.Read** will work correctly. That was the main point of question.

Again, I understand, that this code example is absolutely inefficient. I'm just trying to understand how streams work in that example and does this issue exist because of bad code only (or StreamReader.BaseStream has some issues)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using StreamReader at all?

Comment: @usr Like I said, it is possible to avoid this issue at all without any difficulties. I'm just curious how fact of using property affects internal stream in such strange way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not `StreamReader.BaseStream` has some issues but is a problem in your code. When you work directly with the `Stream` wraped inside `StreamReader`.

From MSDN about [StreamReader.DiscardBufferedData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.discardbuffereddata.aspx):

> You need to call this method only when the position of the internal buffer and the BaseStream do not match. These positions can become mismatched when you read data into the buffer and then seek a new position in the underlying stream.

That mean, in your case, when the `Stream` already reached end position, the position of `StreamReader` **internal buffer** still remain the value before you read the underlying stream directedly, therefore `reader.EndOfStream` still = `false`. That why you can not finish the loop.

**Edit:**

I think you are missing something, I give you this code to prove that the file is successfully reached to the end. Run it and you see that your app repeatly say: *I'm at the end of the file!*

```
static void Main()
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"yourFile"))
    {
        int offset = 0;
        int bufferSize = 102400;
        int length = (int)reader.BaseStream.Length;
        byte[] file = new byte[length];
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {


            // Add this line:
            Console.WriteLine(reader.BaseStream.Position);
            Console.ReadLine();



            int readBytes = reader.BaseStream.Read(file, 0,
                (length - offset) > bufferSize ? bufferSize : (length - offset));
            string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(file, 0, readBytes);
            offset += readBytes;
            if (reader.BaseStream.Position == length)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I'm at the end of the file!  Current Tickcount: " + Environment.TickCount);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**

> But still , offset and length should be equal, im my case length - offset = 1024 (in case of files that bigger than 1kb). Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but if I use files with size less than 1kb, readBytes always equals 0.

That because your first call to `while (!reader.EndOfStream)`, the reader have to read the file (this case is 1024 bytes - read bytes to internal buffer) to detemine if file is ended or not *(see two lines of code I add above)*, after it read the file is seeked 1024 bytes, that why `length - offset = 1024`, and if your file small than 1kb then with this first call, it already seek to end of file. This is where you lost data.

The second call to it, it don't seek because you don't send any read request to the reader, so it consider unchanged, then it don't need read file again to check if at the end of file, that why the second call don't loss data.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I understand that **StreamReader** has internal buffer and his own position. But I was completely disturbed that availability of last 1024 bytes depends on using EndOfStream **property** (not method, which intention is to change state of object). Thing is, that if I delete **reader.EndOfStream** in code, all data will be available. Using wrapper like **StreamReader** affects on accessibility of data in **Stream**, which was wrapped. So I still don't understand how exactly wrapper affects internal stream and why it makes last 1024 bytes inaccessible.

Comment: Thanks for edit. You're right, my app is saying _I'm at the end of the file!_. But still , **offset** and **length** should be equal, im my case   **length - offset = 1024** (in case of files that bigger than 1kb). Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but if I use files with size less than 1kb, **readBytes** always equals 0.

Comment: Thank you for explaination. So, speaking generally, when `EndOfStream` is called, `Stream.Positon` will increase by 1024, if it's possible (and if necessary). And because of inappropriate use of `BaseStream` this will cause data leak. Did I get it right?